# Besides using Expo, what are some good IDE for writing React Native and React code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to find a better way to write and compile my React-based code.

For a class, we wrote our code primarily in Expo.io, which emulated a mobile experience as well as optionally connecting to our phones. I did not find this to be very usable due to the automatic error tagging.

Comment: The question is way too broad and off-topic for SO...

Comment: usually VS code people will use and it is good also